# Call ClassB function from ClassA to hide ClassA widget

Tags: python, tkinter

First, I apologize if I've omitted necessary code. I'm a beginner to coding and this is my first time developing a GUI app -- I'm not sure if I'm showing what you need to assist me.

I am trying to develop a multi-window GUI application for data entry at my company. I have been using page to build pages. I currently have 3 pages, which work individually, and a variety of functions to import and save data. Now I am trying to build a function that hides all widgets on the root window so that I can create/show a new Toplevel without the old widgets being visible.

ClassB contains all widgets for my root window. I am trying to call  ClassA.main_continue, which I want to display pageC widgets and hide all root/classB widgets.

I am receiving an error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object." Python alternates between trying to execute the lines labeled "#####...1" and "#####..2" before exiting with that error.

I have spent 10 hours researching and trying different methods to open a new window and hide the old window. I will eventually have 6-8 windows so I want a separate class that I can use to control them all.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
    top = ClassB (root)

class ClassA: #class that contains functions to control program/do tasks
    def main_continue(self, top):
        ClassC(root)
        x = ClassB(top) ################################## 1
        self.x.main_button1.place_forget()

class ClassB: #root window
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        y = ClassA()

        self.main_button1 = tk.Button(top, command= y.main_continue(top)) ######################2
        self.main_button1.pack()
        self.main_button1.place(relx=0.383, rely=0.5, height=24, width=140)
        self.main_button1.configure(text='''Continue''')

class ClassC: #2nd page
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        ## code for a different page of widgets
```

Comment: There are several was to achieve this. You could simple use a frame in the root window and hide the frame you don't need and show the frame you do need. You could use a toplevel window and hide the root thought I think this is overkill. That said `main_button1`'s command should be a lambda statement or else it will not work the way you expect. Also `self.x` is not going to work here because you define `x` as a variable and not as a class attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to address a few of your issues in your code. `self.x.main_button1.place_forget()` will cause an error as `self.x` does not exist. You need to define `x` as a class attribute first by applying the `self.` prefix. Next you are using `pack()` and `place()` on your button. You do not need to do this. You only need to use one of the 3 geometry managers. My personal preference is `grid()` I find it to be the easiest to use for my layouts. Actually you can reduce your 4 lines of code down to 1 line for that button.

If you are going to use classes to build your GUI I would recommend inherit from Tkinter classes such as the `Tk()` instance and `Frame` or `Toplevel`.

Here is a super simple example of switching frames. There are many ways you can do this but this should be a good start for you.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
main_page = tk.Frame(root)
main_page.grid(row=0, column=0)
second_page = tk.Frame(root)


def show_main_page():
    second_page.grid_forget()
    main_page.grid(row=0, column=0)


def show_second_page():
    main_page.grid_forget()
    second_page.grid(row=0, column=0)

tk.Button(main_page, text='Show 2nd page', command=show_second_page).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(second_page, text='Show Main page', command=show_main_page).grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```